# (Py)GTK StatusIcon notifications on Windows

Tags: python, winapi, gtk, pygtk, notifications

I'm currently writing a screen capture app for Windows and Linux using PyGTK, and I've hit a slight problem with displaying notifications. On Linux, I've been using the libnotify bindings to provide notifications, which has been working very well; however, this has no equivalent on Windows.

I'd [use the Win32 APIs directly](http://www.stromcode.com/2008/03/02/cwin32-the-system-tray-and-balloon-tips/) to display the notification if I could, but I can't seem to find any way to get the tray icon ID from either GTK or PyGTK.

So should I bite the bullet and write a new Windows-specific staus icon class using the Win32 APIs? Or is there a way to initiate a Win32 notification from (Py)GTK that I've missed?

If anyone has any other ideas for displaying simple notifications on Windows, I'd love to hear those too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [GtkStatusIcon source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkstatusicon.c) I don't see the NOTIFYICONDATA exposed anywhere. For X11 there is [get_x11_window_id](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkStatusIcon.html#gtk-status-icon-get-x11-window-id), which has no equivalent and just returns 0 in Windows. Perhaps you could file a bug to request similar functionality.

For now, you'll have to create your own tray icon. A quick search at comp.lang.python gives [useful result](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.general/541418).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This looks as if this is the route I'll have to take.